# Button doesn't trigger command with parameter

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a bad time trying to pass a parameter to a command.

I have the following in XAML code:

```
    <Button Text="{Binding ButtonText}" x:Name="btnCaptureNegotiation" BackgroundColor="#3276b1" 
                        TextColor="White" Clicked="OnCaptureNegotiationClicked"  
                        CommandParameter="{Binding Client, Path=cod_cte}" Command="{Binding LoadULastNegotiationCommand}"  ></Button>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="captureLayout"  IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}">
<!-- more code -->
```

And in code-behind I binded like this:

```
public Client client;
public NegociationVM negotiation = new NegotiationVM();

public ClientItemPage(Client client)
        {
            this.client = client;
          negotiation.Client = client; //STOP WORKING after adding this line
            InitializeComponent();
            captureLayout.BindingContext = negotiation;
            btnCaptureNegotiation.BindingContext = negotiation;
        }

private void OnCaptureNegotiationClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            negotiation.IsVisible = !negotiation.IsVisible;
        }

...
```

And NegotiationVM class:

```
public class NegotiationVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _isVisible = false;
        private string _buttonText = "Capturar Seguimiento";

        private Client _client;
        public Client Client{
            get { return _client; }
            set { 
                if (this._client != value)
                    _client = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Client");
            }
        }

        private Models.NegotiationRepository _negotiationRepo;

        public ICommand LoadULastNegotiationCommand { get; private set; }
        public int LoadLasNegotiationResult { get; private set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public NegotiationVM(){

            LoadULastNegotiationCommand = new Command<string (LoadLastNegotiationAsync);
        }


        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        async void LoadLastNegotiationAsync(string value)
        {
            _negotiationRepo = new Models.NegotiationRepository();
            LoadLasNegotiationResult = await _negotiationRepo.GetLastNegotiationActiveAsync(value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("LoadLastNegotiationAsync");
        }

        public bool IsVisible
        {
            get
            {
                return _isVisible;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this._isVisible != value)
                    _isVisible = value;
                if (this._isVisible){
                    this.ButtonText = "Cancel";
                }else{
                    this.ButtonText = "Capture Negotation";
                }
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsVisible");
            }
        }

        public string ButtonText {
            get
            {
                return _buttonText;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this._buttonText != value)
                    _buttonText = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ButtonText");
            }
        }
}
```

I found that the command is fired and tries to get resource from service, but I get 404 because I found that is not sending a parameter, I just put a breakpoint in  async void LoadLastNegotiationAsync(string value) method to find that.

Because it wasn't sending anything, In code-behind Page, in the public constructor, I set the Client to the property of the same name in negotation (instance of NegotiationVM). As the comment suggest, the command STOP working and never gets fired by the button just by adding that line.

What is wrong with that binding? How can I properly send the string property of that Client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Cliente` has a property named `cod_cte`. bind like so:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding Cliente.cod_cte}"
```

If the property is named `Client` rather than `Cliente`, omit the trailing `e` on `Cliente`:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding Client.cod_cte}"
```